# Why is the area of upstream face of control volume a stated?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, geometry

I cannot seem to visualise why the area of the upstream face of control volume is 2pir∂r, can someone pls clarify on why is this the case?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the very thin layer of $\delta r$.

if we peel it off and stretch it like a very thin rectangular with $L=2\pi r$ and thickness as $\delta r, \ $ its area will be $A=l*\delta r= 2\pi r*\delta r$

Comment: That makes so much more sense, thanks!